# Vue-cli-service serve build completion callback?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'd like to fire up a vue-cli dev server, then run a command from node once this build has completed.

Is there a way to run `vue-cli-service serve` from a node script so that I can receive a callback once the dev server is up and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`vue-cli-service.js`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/b1f3a4c/packages/%40vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js) does not return the service promise (which would've allowed you to setup a completion callback), but you could make a copy of the script (25 lines) to do so:

<sub>*my-vue-cli-service.js:*</sub>

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const semver = require('semver')
const { error } = require('@vue/cli-shared-utils')
const requiredVersion = require('@vue/cli-service/package.json').engines.node

if (!semver.satisfies(process.version, requiredVersion)) {
  error(
    `You are using Node ${process.version}, but vue-cli-service ` +
    `requires Node ${requiredVersion}.\nPlease upgrade your Node version.`
  )
  process.exit(1)
}

const Service = require('@vue/cli-service')
const service = new Service(process.env.VUE_CLI_CONTEXT || process.cwd())

const rawArgv = process.argv.slice(2)
const args = require('minimist')(rawArgv)
const command = args._[0]

module.exports = () =>  // <--- add this line to return the service promise
  service.run(command, args, rawArgv).catch(err => {
    error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

Then, you could create another script that consumes this copy, adding a `then` callback to be invoked when the server started successfully:

<sub>*my-service.js:*</sub>

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const service = require('./my-vue-cli-service')

service().then(result => {
  if (result && result.server) {  // <--- server started successfully if result.server exists
    const {server, url} = result;
    console.log('ready');
  }
})
```

Be sure to update `package.json` to use the new script:

<sub>*package.json:*</sub>

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "./my-service.js serve"
  }
}
```