# How to force exit an vue cli thread on completion in a deploy script (e.g. ctrl c equivelant)

Tags: vue.js, continuous-deployment, vue-cli, npm-scripts, laravel-forge

I'm using Laravel Forge to run a simple deploy script.  npm run build calls 'vue-cli-service build'.

Script below.  The script 'ends' on

DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

but the thread does not quit, which causes issues in forge (e.g. thinks it's timed out or failed when it hasn't).

How do I do the equivelant of ctrl-c in a terminal once this has finished, in the deploy script?  I've seen threads on trap SIGINT / trap etc. but I'm still not really sure how to implement it.

It may be that I just include the exit callback fix noted here: [Vue-cli-service serve build completion callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130907/vue-cli-service-serve-build-completion-callback)

````
git pull origin $FORGE_SITE_BRANCH;
npm run build;
 
( flock -w 10 9 || exit 1
    echo 'Restarting FPM...'; sudo -S service $FORGE_PHP_FPM reload ) 9>/tmp/fpmlock

if [ -f artisan ]; then
    $FORGE_PHP artisan migrate --force
fi```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try out to add Daemon termination command to the end of your deployment script

```
$FORGE_PHP artisan horizon:terminate
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a vue project rather than laravel so artisan doesn't exist.  Trying to exit once npm run build is complete, so it's npm.